# Nginx specify regex for searching in file names

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

How can I specify in my conf file so that

given request: `/find/{xyz}`

nginx would search for and serve file with name:
`some_arbitrary_prefix.{xyz}.html`
where `some_arbitrary_prefix` might be any random string before dot?

EDIT:
I don't understand, why `regex` tag was deleted from question?
In other words, I guess what I'm asking is: can one use regex to filter target files rather than locations?

Comment: If you are asking Nginx to guess the filename - then that is not possible.

Comment: Not guess, but filter filenames by regex and serve first one that matches? Anyway, I got your point, thanks

Comment: There are language extensions such as lua and Perl that may be able to do it, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to extract the part of the URI following `/find/`, and then use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) to construct the path to the filename.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/find/(.*)$ {
    root /path/to/folder;
    try_files /someprefix.$1.html =404;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention that `someprefix` can be anything (edited my question) and unknowable. Can I use something like `try_files /(.*).$1.html =404` in config?